# Changing variable names in code so I don't have to repeat large chunks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    switch (name)
    {
    case "One":
        if (UpgradeOne_CostNextUpgrade <= TotalCash){//Decides if you have enough money to purchase upgrade 1
            TotalCash -= Float_CostOfNextUpgradeOne; //Subtracts the cost of upgrade 1 from TotalCash
            Int_UpgradeOneOwned += 1;//Increases count of upgrade 1 by 1
        }//end if
        break;    ...
```

So I am interested in running similar code as show above for 10 different upgrades. I made a case statement for each case but find the code will have to be repeated each time. I want to change the variable names somehow in code so I can use the same block 10 times. How might I do this? Thanks

Comment: will the code be repeated verbatim?  or will the code be changed, like change "UpgradeOne" to "UpgradeTwo" in the case of "Two" (for example)?

Comment: Side note: SO assumes some basic knowledge of programming languages. Adding comment like `v = v+1; "//Increases count of ... by 1"` is really not necessary.

Comment: If you could edit your post to show how your switch looks currently with 2 or 3 case statements then it would be a lot easier to answer your question.

Comment: You may consider removing the `unity3d` tag, as there's nothing specific to it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you use arrays?

```
float[] upgradeCosts  = new float[] { cost1, cost2, cost3 ... };
int[] upgradesOwned = new int[10];
int choice = -1;
switch (name)
{
    // this might be confusing, but arrays in C# are zero-based
    case "One":   choice = 0; break;
    case "Two":   choice = 1; break;
    case "Three": choice = 2; break;
    ...
 }

 if (choice > -1 && upgradeCosts[choice] <= TotalCash){//Decides if you have enough money to purchase upgrade 1
        TotalCash -= upgradeCosts[choice]; //Subtracts the cost of upgrade 1 from TotalCash
        upgradesOwned[choice] += 1;//Increases count of upgrade 1 by 1
 } //end if
```

If you want to help readability, you could store an array with 11 elements and not use the data at 0, but the obvious downside is that you're allocating more memory than you need to. It might be a worthwhile trade-off though.

---

As a side note, you shouldn't use `float`s or `double`s to store monetary values because they are imprecise. C# has a `decimal` type for higher precision.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same code for multiple cases, you can fall through empty cases to a non-empty one:

```
switch (name)
{
    case "One" :
    case "Two" :
    case "Three" :
        Console.WriteLine("One, two or three");
        break;
}
```

I am not sure what you mean by changing variable names. I doubt `name` refers to the actual name of a variable. Are you using reflection?

Comment: Each case changes different variables though. Like the variable "UpgradeOne_CostNextUpgrade." I'd like to just use the same block of code but somehow change different variables every time.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework question and you didn't post your code, so I'm only posting concepts, not code.

Declare two arrays, UpgradePrice[] and UpgradeOwned[].  Initialize  the prices in the first, and set the second to all FALSE.

Now you can iterate through, using a loop.  First test if the upgrade is not already been purchased.  Then test the cash available against upgrade price.

You can also extend this to offer a series of upgrades.  Make UpgradeOwned an integer instead of a boolean.  Define two-dimensional array UpgradePrice[10, 5]  Then you can test if (CashAvailable > UpgradePrice[i, UpgradesOwned[i]]).  Be sure you stop testing for upgrades when UpgradesOwned[i] gets too big, or you will have a bounds violation.